# Null Object on XML Camera Intent on API =>24

Tags: android, android-intent, camera, android-7.0-nougat

I was trying to make the camera intent work on higher APIs but its crashing when i try to. I think there is something wrong with some paths but i cant figure out what. Its running fine with API 23.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                    Process: ur.mi.android.wgplus05, PID: 22088
                                                                    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.res.XmlResourceParser android.content.pm.PackageItemInfo.loadXmlMetaData(android.content.pm.PackageManager, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.parsePathStrategy(FileProvider.java:583)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getPathStrategy(FileProvider.java:557)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.content.FileProvider.getUriForFile(FileProvider.java:399)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:50)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity.takePicture(PictureActivity.java:148)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity.checkPermission(PictureActivity.java:140)
                                                                        at ur.mi.android.wgplus05.PictureActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(PictureActivity.java:101)
                                                                        at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:3204)
                                                                        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:408)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:113)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:679)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.dispatchMenuItemSelected(MenuBuilder.java:822)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuItemImpl.invoke(MenuItemImpl.java:156)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:969)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuBuilder.performItemAction(MenuBuilder.java:959)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView.invokeItem(ActionMenuView.java:623)
                                                                        at android.support.v7.view.menu.ActionMenuItemView.onClick(ActionMenuItemView.java:154)
                                                                        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
                                                                        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22260)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:865)
                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
```

Line 50:

```
   Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activityContext,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".genericfileprovider",
                    photoFile);


  public class Camera {
PictureActivity activityContext;
private String currentPhotoPath;

public Camera(PictureActivity activityContext) {
    this.activityContext = activityContext;
}

public void takePicture(int requestCode) {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activityContext.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        try {
            photoFile = createImageFile();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            // Error occurred while creating the File
            return;
        }
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created

        if (photoFile != null) {
            if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 24){
            Uri photoURI = Uri.fromFile(photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            activityContext.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
        }
        else {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activityContext,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".genericfileprovider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);
            activityContext.startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, requestCode);
        }
        }
    }
}

public String getCurrentPhotoPath() {
    return currentPhotoPath;
}

public Bitmap getScaledBitmap(String path, Point targetSize) {
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
    BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);

    int photoW = bmOptions.outWidth;
    int photoH = bmOptions.outHeight;


    int scaleFactor = Math.min(photoW / targetSize.x, photoH / targetSize.y);

    bmOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = scaleFactor;
    bmOptions.inPurgeable = true;

    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, bmOptions);

    return bitmap;
}

private File createImageFile() throws IOException {
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.ENGLISH).format(new Date());
    String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
    File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
    File image = File.createTempFile(imageFileName, ".jpg", storageDir);

    currentPhotoPath = image.getAbsolutePath();

    return image;

}
```

}

Manifest:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"
    android:required="true"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_icon_hdx"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_icon_hdx"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">


        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Finanzen" />
    <activity android:name=".Einkaufsliste" />
    <activity android:name=".Einkaufsliste2" />
    <activity android:name=".toDoList" />
    <activity android:name=".Settings" />
    <activity android:name=".PictureActivity" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Putzplan"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
    <activity android:name=".Kalender" />
    <provider
        android:name=".GenericFileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.ur.mi.android.wgplus05.genericfileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
</application>
</manifest>
```

thats path

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-path name="external_files" path="."/>
</paths>
```

Comment: I think its permission issue use run time permission

Answer (score 1):

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.ur.mi.android.wgplus05.genericfileprovider"

BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".genericfileprovider"
```

These do not match. They need to match. Otherwise, `FileProvider` cannot find the `ContentProvider`, because you provided an invalid authority name to `getUriForFile()`.

So, for example, you could change the first line to:

```
android:authorities="${applicationId}.genericfileprovider"
```

Then, the two values would match (application ID plus `.genericfileprovider`).

Comment: okay if i do: android:authorities="${applicationId}.genericfileprovider" it should work?

Comment: @boom3x: It should get you past that error, at least. You have other issues (`android.hardware.camera.autofocus` is not a permission, you are not holding onto `currentPhotoPath` in case of configuration changes or your process being terminated when the camera app is in the foreground). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/v8.7/Camera/FileProvider) demonstrates how to use `ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE` with `FileProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument in `getUriForFile` should match the `authorities` attribute from the xml.

```
BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".ur.mi.android.wgplus05.genericfileprovider"
```